# Space not space on string

Tags: string, excel, vba, space

I have a cell in Excel that is pasted from outlook. When I read it in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), there is some spaces on it and I need to remove.
It took me some hours to find the solution to remove it.

I tried:

- `Replace(string_value," ","")` and did not remove the spaces
- `Application.find(" ", string_value)` and returned error
- `Application.trim(string_value)` and did not remove the spaces
  ...

My solution:

```
string_value = Replace(Str(string_value), " ", "")
```

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you show us the declraation of your `string_value` variable? I have an idea, but I need to confirm.

Comment: @RubberDuck got a point, if my idea is the same as his idea, I think you're getting a full HTML string. See my answers for more details about what I think it's going on. It would be great if you would show us how you assign the value to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook emails can be written in two modes:

1) Plain text;

2) HTML (for allowing colors, layouts etc.)

You probably are into the second case, because a table cannot be inserted in plain text mode, and when you get the value of the variable `string_value` you get it in full HTML string.

What happens in fact is that Outlook converts your body in HTML to allow it being viewed from any mail server (HTML is the international web language, read by any browser uniformally, or almost). Which means, the character *space* will not any longer be `" "`, but rather its HTML equivalent, i.e. `&nbsp` (or something else, I don't know if there's a breakline or not, I'm not a real expert of HTML).

Hence, when you use one of the three methods above, none of them is able to find the "visual space", or better the string character `" "`. However, when you use the function `Str()`, the HTML string will be re-converted to VBA Language (i.e. `&nbsp` or equivalent will be converted in `" "` and your approach will hence work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the statement:

```
string_value = Replace(Str(string_value), " ", "")
```

does several things.  Usually *str()* takes a *Long* argument.  Becuase you are giving it a *String,* VBA (in the background) converts the string to a *Long.*  In doing this it discards any junk characters (non-digits) like CHR(160).
*Str()* pads the result with a blank, which *Replace()* removes !

[`Str` Function  on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263370(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use:

`Replace(string_value,CHAR(160),"")`